# how to get source code text in ruby?

Tags: ruby

inspired by some lisp magic of runtime edit sourcecode,

I want to do it in ruby. looks like I cannot get sourcecode from method/class,
is there a way to do it?

I write a sample sourcecode here:

```
def helloworld n
  "hello #{n}"
end

o = Kernel.method :helloword

Kernel.define_singleton_method o.name do |n|
  eval o.source_code.sub('hello', 'hello world')
end

helloworld 'halida' #=> 'hello world halida'
```

Comment: See the similar questions on Stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740684/ruby-get-source-code or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393096/how-can-i-get-source-code-of-a-methods-dynamically-and-also-which-file-is-this-m or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719649/ruby-print-source-code or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164903/find-the-source-of-eval-code ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the string representation of a part of the code, edit it and expect Ruby to reevaluate your changes. The only way to do something near to what you want is using `ParseTree` to get s-expressions of the source, edit and use `Ruby2Ruby` to generate a string of ruby code. Them add `def ...` and `end` to the string and call eval with it.

It's too hard and error-prone to be useful in a real-world situation. But I don't know any other way.

Note: ParseTree only works on Ruby 1.8.

Comment: You absolutely can get a string representation of the source code. Just use `.method.source` for class methods or  `.instance_method.source` for instance methods. If you want to edit the string and reapply it you can just open the class redefine the method and use `eval` on the new string.

Comment: See also `class_eval` and `instance_eval`

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get source code for a method in Ruby.

Imagine the following hypothetical class:

```
class Klass
  def self.foo
    :foo
  end

  def bar
    :bar
  end
end
```

As you can see, this class has two methods:

- a class method .foo
- an instance method #bar

Use `.method` and `.instance_method` to access them programmatically:

```
m1 = Klass.method :foo
=> #<Method: Klass.foo>

m2 = Klass.instance_method :bar
=> #<UnboundMethod: Klass#bar>
```

You can use the `.source` method to view their source code:

```
puts m1.source
  def self.foo
    :foo
  end
=> nil

puts m2.source
  def self.bar
    :bar
  end
=> nil
```

Because Ruby has open classes and dynamic loading, you can also add or 
change methods at run time. Just re-open the class and redefine the method:

```
Klass.foo
=> :foo

class Klass
  def self.foo
    :foobar
  end
end

Klass.foo
=> :footer
```

The other methods previously defined in the class will remain unaffected:

```
Klass.bar
=> :bar
```

**WARNING**: Redefining class behavior during runtime (also called "Monkey Patching") 
is a very powerful tool, it can also be somewhat dangerous. Current versions of Ruby
support a much more controlled way of going about this called 'refinements'.

You can [learn more about using refinements here](http://blog.headius.com/2012/11/refining-ruby.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [method_source](https://github.com/banister/method_source) gem. It's used by [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) REPL for `show-method` command.

Looks like this gem utilizes standard `Method#source_location` (available in Ruby 1.9) to locate method and get its source code. Obviously, it doesn't work for dynamically defined methods and C methods. See docs for more information.